# Html Css buttons look different in Firefox

Tags: css, styles

I have a css definiton for all my buttons as below. However my buttons looks strange in mozilla firefox. They look fine for all browsers except firfox  mozilla. I could find why. can you check it.

FireFox:

[image]

Chrome

[image]

Html button

```
<button class="btn btnFB btnBig"  >Signin By Facebook </button>
```

Css Definition

```
.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
    overflow: visible;
    padding: 7px 2px 7px 20px;
    font-size: 0.97em;
    font-weight: bold;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-transition: all .15s linear;
    -moz-transition: all .15s linear;
    transition: all .15s linear;
    text-shadow: 1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(255, 255, 255,0.3)), to(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3),rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3),rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3),rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3),rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3),rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
}

button.btnFB{background-color: #3b5998;border-color: #3b5998;color: #FEF3E5;}
button.btnFB:hover{background-color: #4966A5;}
button.btnFB:active{background-color: #3b5998;}
button.btnBig{line-height: 1.33em;padding: 8px 12px 8px 30px;}
```

EDIT : 
The font family of my web site

```
body{
    font: normal 12px RobotoDraft,Roboto,'Helvetica Neue',arial,sans-serif;
    background-color: #F7F7F7;
    color: #262626;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do not set fonts on your page, each browser uses its default fonts. This may well mean that the font family used in `button` elements varies. It is typically Arial, but Firefox has different settings, e.g. MS Shell Dlg in my system (Win 7). You can check such issues using each browser’s Developer Tools.

There’s also a difference in font size. When you set font size to `0.97em`, browsers multiply the parent element’s font size by 0.97 and may then round the result, even in different ways. When the basic font size is the typical default of 16px, IE uses 15.52px, Firefox uses the correct exact value 15.53px, and Chrome uses 16px (i.e. rounds to in integral number of pixels). This, combined with font family variation, causes small differences.

You can make the rendering more uniform by replacing `font-size: 0.97em` by

```
font-size: 1em;
```

and adding

```
font-family: Arial;
```

in the rule with the `.btn` selectors.

This does not remove all differences, since browsers render fonts in slightly different ways, and not all systems have Arial (many modern handheld devices don’t). Rendering in Firefox and Chrome on Win 7:

[image]

Regarding font family, you could use a downloadable font (web font), to get more consistent results. Doing so just for a few buttons might be overkill, but maybe you have other use for it too.

Comment: Since this is facebook button, i would had liked to use klavika but  it gives different result for non-english letters. So I decied my buttons have the same font-family with my body. Furthermore, I set my button font-size 1em. but nothing changed. still in firefox it looks terrible

Comment: I don’t see what you mean by “terrible”. To me, the Chrome rendering (the lower one in the added screenshot) looks worse, because bolding is somewhat disproportionate. But this is a matter of taste, too, and it depends on rendering details we cannot control.

Comment: I think your answer is correct. When i set font-family: Arial; for my button it worked. as in your image also, bold meausures are different. why I can not use font: normal 12px RobotoDraft,Roboto,'Helvetica Neue',arial,sans-serif; for my buttons also?

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer.  The problem was my font-family. I did what you adviced. It is much better then what I did.

Answer (score 2):

What is the font-family of your site ? This look like a font-familly issue. Not all browser display all font the same way. If you specified more then one, maybe firefox don't find one and fallback to another one.

Answer (score 1):

Default font used by Chrome is different to that used by Firefox. Hence it looks different.

You can find a lot of fonts on **Google Fonts**.

If still you didn't find one, try the **Roboto** font from Google's **Material Design**.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a `line-height` issue. Try to add something like this:

`line-height: 1.5;`

See if that helps.

Comment: no it did not help. BTW i changed em to px.. it worked little bit but in firefox, text in button are not exactly centered horizontally like in chrome or safari or ie